# Testing uniform convergence of a sequence of functions involving sums of arctan

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

The problem states as follows:

Test whether the following sequence converges uniformly on $(0,\infty)$

$$
f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \arctan\frac{k^2x}{n^3}
$$

Firstly I don't know how to find this sum or if it is even possible. I have tried finding a pattern in first few terms and with intention to find a formula which I would later prove inductively with no luck.

I have however managed to prove pointwise convergence by finding an upper bound ($\frac{x}{3}$) and noticing that the sequence is increasing I deduced that it must converge.

In this situation I would usually use Cauchy's test for uniform convergence, but I had no luck with it.

Comment: On this interval, $\arctan$ is non-negative bounded by $\dfrac{\pi}{2},$ use Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: I have tried binding it by using arctgx < x on (0,inf). But that led me to this sum being less than x/3 which isnt sufficient, and I dont see how I can use the fact that arctan is less than pi/2.

Comment: I understand what I got wrong, I thought the $n^3$ was dividing the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If the sequence $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $(0,\infty)$, then

$$f_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x)=\arctan \left (\frac{n^2x}{n^3}\right ) \to 0\,\,\text{uniformly on}\,(0,\infty).$$